# Has anyone connected to Oracle from SSIS using Oracle Driver ( 12.1.0 ) from VS 2017 Data Tools SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have installed Oracle Driver ( 12.1.0 ) and I have VS 2017 Data Tools SSIS . The connection to Oracle Service from local machine via ODBC 64 bit on my machine is working.

Connection to Oracle Server from SSMS 17 via Linked Server is not working

I get 'Architecture Mismatch' error when I create a Oracle OLDEB connection from SSIS.
Any ideas how do I access Oracle from SSMS and SSIS  ..

Thanks,
Shuchi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio and SSDT are 32bit programs, so they can't use the 64bit OleDB provider.  You can run your SSIS package in 64bit mode, but the designers don't work unless you also have the 32bit OleDB provider, and are running visual studio using a Path that allows it to load the 32bit OCI.DLL.

Comment: Thanks David. Does that mean I need to install 32 Bit ODBC connector and then try connecting to Oracle from my Visual Studio 2017 . I will first have to check if the connection to Oracle works using 32 Bit Driver.

Comment: Thanks David.  I have a Windows 10 and when I try to install 32 Bit ODBC driver it comes with error. Apparently 32 bit drivers needs Windows 8 or earlier versions. I am unable to connect to Oracle from my Windows 10 machine , using SSIS / SSDT.

Answer (score 0):

On a windows 2016 server I was forced to use oracle 12C drivers. I installed 32 and 64 bit and can connect and execute sql via sql developer, sqlserver 2016 linked server but not from visual studio 2017 SSIS in debug mode although the connection tests OK.